# How to allow convert phone number in specific format on change in the angular js using custom directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I want to create one custom directive in angular js which allows user to enter value in format 555-555-555 during input and pass the value to controller each time user enter or delete the digit of number from input field. Can any one have idea how to do that.

Comment: Can you provide some code and/or anything you've already tried?  Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40326306/ng-change-function-in-angularjs-custom-directive-updating-input-value-after-seco/40326461#40326461

Comment: Look at the [ngModelController API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController). Look into adding a parser function to the `$parsers` array. Parsers are used to sanitize / convert the `$viewValue`.